# Is it possible to share public IP pools between routers?

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have a public IP block assigned to me. I would like to be able to assign addresses from it to clients on different routers without assigning a subnet to each router or anything like that.

Here is a diagram indicating what I want: 
[image: Diagram of sharing public IP pool between routers]

**For example, if one of my Public pools is 5.250.14.0/24 then :**
Can PPPoE AC1 assign 5.250.14.1 and PPPoE AC2 assign 5.250.14.2 to their clients?

**Note :** Because the RADIUS server manages the IP pool assignments, we will not have duplicate IP assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The RADIUS server must take care of assigning the IP address, and the Mikrotik routers will listen to whatever IP the RADIUS server gives the client. Since you are using PPPoE, there will be no problems with broadcast domains. If you weren't, you would likely have to use a private /30 as a point-to-point link and then tell the router to route the public IP to the endpoint of the /30.

Comment: @user762709 If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept.